# Class Cast Exception from Comparable to Integer type

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a generic MergeSort sorting algorithm. the function only accepts the type that implements Comparable interface as well as display function takes an array of any type to display the content of the array. But I'm receiving this exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/[Ljava.lang.Comparable; cannot be cast to java.base/[Ljava.lang.Integer;
```

at mergeSort.MergeSort.main(MergeSort.java:10)

My code is below:

```
package mergeSort;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer[] array = new Integer[]{3, 4, 2, 9, 5, 7, 8, 1, 6};
        display(mergeSort(array));
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] mergeSort(T[] array)
    {
        if(array.length <= 1) return array;

        int leftLength = array.length/2;
        int rightLength = array.length - leftLength;

        T[] left = (T[]) new Comparable[leftLength];
        T[] right = (T[]) new Comparable[rightLength];

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if(i < leftLength)
            {
                left[i] = array[i];
            }
            else
            {
                right[Math.abs(left.length-i)] = array[i];
            }
        }

        return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right));
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] merge(T[] left, T[] right)
    {
        T[] merged = (T[]) new Comparable[left.length + right.length];

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;

        while(i < left.length && j < right.length)
        {
            if(left[i].compareTo(right[j]) < 0)
            {
                merged[k++] = left[i++];
            }
            else
            {
                merged[k++] = right[j++];
            }
        }

        while(i < left.length) merged[k++] = left[i++];
        while(j < right.length) merged[k++] = right[j++];

        return merged;
    }

    public static <T> void display(T[] array)
    {
        Arrays.stream(array).forEach(value -> System.out.print(value + " "));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, the error is actually saying it couldn't cast `Comparable[]` (array) to `Integer[]`. This `[Lfoo.Bar;` is how Java array types are notated in some places.

Answer (score 3):

This method declaration promises something it doesn't do:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] mergeSort(T[] array)
```

You're not returning `T[]`. You're returning `Comparable[]`. So, either just declare it as such:

```
public static Comparable<?>[] mergeSort(Comparable<?>[] array) { ... }
public static Comparable<?>[] merge(Comparable<?>[] left, Comparable<?>[] right) { ... }
```

Alternatively, create your arrays using `Array.newInstance()`. For example:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] merge(T[] left, T[] right) {
    T[] merged = (T[]) Array.newInstance(
        left.getClass().getComponentType(), 
        left.length + right.length);
    ...
```

Comment: Now I've this error after I changed type T[] to Comparable<?>[] Error:(50, 39) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Comparable<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to capture#2 of ?  code is here https://pastebin.com/DKtRcMVy

Comment: Right. Well, you can either revert to using generics but return `Comparable<?>[]` in your methods, or cast the argument of `compareTo` to the raw type `Comparable`: `left[i].compareTo((Comparable) right[j])`